# QD C*-algebra's representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Here is a question from the proof of the "QD C*-algebra's representation theorem" in P245 of book "C*-algebras and Finite-Dimensional Approximations" by Nate and Taka.

> For a separable unital C*-algebra $A$,  let $\phi_{n}: A\rightarrow M_{k(n)}(\mathbb{C})$ be u.c.p maps which are asymptotically multiplicative (i.e., $||\phi_{n}(ab)-\phi_{n}(a)\phi_{n}(b)||\rightarrow 0$ for all $a, b\in A$) and isometric (i.e., $||a||=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}||\phi_{n}(a)||$ for all $a\in A$). Consider the u.c.p. map
>   $$\Phi: A\rightarrow \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}M_{k(n)}(\mathbb{C})\subset B(\bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty}\ell_{k(n)}^{2}),~~\Phi(a)=\bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty}\phi_{n}(a).$$
>
> Then, $\Phi$ is a faithful representation modulo the compact.

**My question are**:

1. How to verify $\Phi$ is a representation modulo the compact? (I think the "faithful" is easy from the isometric.)
2. In the proof, the author says $\Phi$ obviously has finite-rank projections which commute with its image and tend strongly to one. What are the "obvious" finite-rank projections?

Now, I attach the definition of representation modulo the compact in P19 of this book.

> If $\pi: B(H)\rightarrow Q(H)$ is the canonical mapping onto the Calkin algebra, $A$ is a unital C*-algebra and $\phi: A\rightarrow B(H)$ is a unital completely positive map, then we say that $\phi$ is a *representation modulo the compacts* if $\pi\circ\phi: A\rightarrow Q(H)$ is a *-homomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the rank of each $\phi_n$ is finite-dimensional, finite direct sums like $\bigoplus_1^m\phi_n$ are compact (actually, they are finite-rank). So, in the quotient, $\bigoplus_1^\infty\phi_n(a)$ and $\bigoplus_m^\infty\phi_n$ are equal, and so
\begin{align}
\|\pi\circ\Phi(ab)-[\pi\circ\Phi(a)]\,[\pi\circ\Phi(b)]\|&=\|\pi\left(\bigoplus_1^\infty(\phi_n(ab)-\phi(a)\phi(b)\right)\|\\
&=\|\pi\left(\bigoplus_m^\infty(\phi_n(ab)-\phi(a)\phi(b))\right)\|\\
&\leq\|\bigoplus_m^\infty(\phi_n(ab)-\phi(a)\phi(b))\|\\
&=\sup_m\|\phi_n(ab)-\phi(a)\phi(b)\|\to0\\
\end{align}
as $m$ goes to infinity. Thus $\pi\circ\Phi(ab)=[\pi\circ\Phi(a)]\,[\pi\circ\Phi(b)]$.

The "obvious rank-one projections" are $\displaystyle\bigoplus_{n=1}^mI_{k(n)}$, $m=1,2,\ldots$

Comment: Aha, I got the point. Thanks a lot~ :P